# Is there a way to remove a custom Object from every occurrence?

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove every GameObject which meet certain criteria (health<0), completely from every occurrence, so every ArrayList it might be in, and such.

I have a main ArrayList containing every GameObject that may get removed, and I'm trying to iterate through that ArrayList with a For-Each, checking each element for the criteria, and removing it.

This however results in ConcurrentModificationException, which I know the reason to, but do not know how to work around it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use iterator to do that as iterator.remove() will not cause taht exception.

Comment: See [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate))

Comment: Just initialize the ArrayList like this: `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<GameObject>());`

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj this will not solve the problem though

Comment: @Lino You're right of course, I didn't read carefully. Thought that the issue is from some other thread modifying the array, not that the removal algorithm is wrong from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JacobG. mentioned in his comment, perhaps the "best" way to do this (where "best" is going to be a matter of personal preference) is via the `.removeIf()` method.  Here's an example (which assumes a `getHealth()` method on your objects):

```
List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();

// Some code here to populate the list

gameObjects.removeIf(x -> x.getHealth() < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have all the items to be removed in a separate ArrayList, you could use `CollectionUtils.subtract()` method from apache-commons-collections to remove them from other lists :

```
yourList = (ArrayList<GameObject>)CollectionUtils.subtract(yourList, listWithObjectsToRemove);
```

See this [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-)